# Protecting Macro Enabled worksheet in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a 4 sheet workbook of employee over time. The first 3 sheets are where the data is added by others. The 4th sheet is where the data is added up.  On this 4th sheet I have enabled an auto sort macro to constantly reorder the data I have on several different tables. Id like to protect this 4th sheet to make it tamper proof, but I found that whenever I protect the sheet, the formulas still work, however the macro does not. I know the macro works because whenever I unprotect the sheet the macro activates again. Do I need to add something to my macro to make it work in protected mode or am I simply doing something wrong or this something that is not capable with excel 2010? This is the macro im currently using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
On Error Resume Next
    Range("c1").Sort Key1:=Range("c2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
On Error Resume Next
    Range("k1").Sort Key1:=Range("k2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

On Error Resume Next
    Range("o1").Sort Key1:=Range("o2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
On Error Resume Next
    Range("s1").Sort Key1:=Range("s2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: When you protect the sheet, try enabling "Sort" in the list of options (may have to scroll down to see it) that appear in the Protect Sheet dialog.

Comment: You can unprotect the sheet in your sort macro, then re-protect at the end.  BTW `On Error Resume Next` remains in force until you cancel it - you only need one of those lines...

Answer (score 0):

You've got a friend you can work with. This friend is called `userinterfaceonly`.

At the beginning of your code, add the following:

```
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Whatever"
    ActiveSheet.Protect _
        Password:= "Whatever", _
        userinterfaceonly:=True
```

This will remove sheet protection, then reactivate it with the UserInterfaceOnly property, which allows changes to be made by the macro, but not by the user. Unfortunately, this property can't be saved, so we need the code to either run whenever the file is opened, or when the worksheet is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you need to unlock the sheet before you call the sort function I think

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    sheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    sheet.Range({whatever range you want}).Locked = False    
    On Error Resume Next
        Range("c1").Sort Key1:=Range("c2"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    On Error Resume Next
      Range("k1").Sort Key1:=Range("k2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
sheet.protect Password:="password"
sheet.Range({whatever range you want}).Locked = True
End Sub
```